# Jest test is not executed in order when debugging

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, debugging, jestjs, phpstorm

I just came across a very strange behavior while writing tests in a `TypeScript` project using `jest` and `PhpStorm`.

I've made a simplified example to illustrate the problem:

[image]

To explain what's going on:

I run the test 3 times:

1. The first time with all the lines and the debugger, it **fails** on **line 14** where it should not, because `mutated` should still be `false` at this point.
2. The second time with the **line 15** commented out and the debugger. It succeeds the where it failed before.
3. With all the lines but **without** the debugger, it succeeds.

So the point here is not to discuss if it's good or bad to have a mutation in a getter.

The point is to understand why the **line 15** is executed *before* the **line 14** when the debugger is active?

I put the code below so you can read it more easily:

```js
class Foo {
    public mutated: boolean = false;

    public get getMe(): string {
        this.mutated = true;
        return 'me';
    }
}

test('state of mutated', () => {
    const foo = new Foo();
    expect(foo.mutated).toEqual(false);
    expect(foo.getMe).toEqual('me');
    expect(foo.mutated).toEqual(true);
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with execution order - the calls are executed in the right order. That's a different issue: with **Enable auto expressions in Variables view** enabled in **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views**, the debugger tries to evaluate expressions to calculate variables values once a breakpoint is hit. So it evaluates `foo.getMe` - as a result, `foo.mutated` becomes `true` and the test fails.

I'm not sure if this can be treated as a bug or expected behavior. I can only suggest disabling this option when dealing with code like yours

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation, it makes perfect sense. I was able to get around the issue by putting the access to the getter in a IIFE (`expect((() => foo.getMe)()).toEqual('me')`), without really understanding why it did work. Now it's clear, thanks again.